# What's a word for being curious in a worried manner?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> My wife was reading the news, her hands shaking, her mouth
>   hanging open.
>
> [...], I leaned over to have a peek.

Is there a word a bit "stronger" than curious? One that shows a bit of apprehension?

Comment: I originally misread your title (I thought you wanted a word stronger than curious which *didn't* have shades of worry); I've deleted my inapplicable answer. I think SpeedyGonzales' *anxious* is spot-on. You might also consider "*concerned*" or plain old *worried*.

Comment: @DanBron You're right. How about now?

Comment: What was wrong with "Apprehensively..."?

Comment: Your title asks for "curious in a worried manner", but *anxiously* or *hesitantly* fits well into the blank in your example sentence. We can assume that the *I* in the sentence is motivated by curiosity. These two words alone mean nothing about curiosity. I think your question can be more helpful to other readers if you can make it clearer.

Comment: Well, "to have a peek" is the very opposite of what you're looking for, so that's a start.  Alarmed...

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the answers are just types of worry and not curiosity.  I think that points fairly directly towards the unlikeliness of finding an acceptable single-word solution.

Comment: *Piqued* would imply more agitation than apprehension, but might work in your context.

Comment: In this context, I would consider saying "Gulping" or "Swallowing hard" or some action that conveys apprehension.  Curiosity is taken care of with "have a peek" and so you don't really need it.

Comment: If the question was to define "curiosity *about* someone *else's* worry",  authoritas's answer is spot on, with *morbid*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Concerned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concerned):

> - feeling or showing worry or solicitude.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 14):

What do you think about [anxious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anxious) -  worried and tense because of possible misfortune, danger, etc; uneasy.

Comment: I think that speedyGonazales makes a good point (I would, however, have used in that example the word 'troubled').

Comment: Anxious means worried. The question asks for a word meaning curious and worried.

Comment: to me, anxious has a dual meaning. "the children sat anxiously anticipating opening their christmas gifts". "The man was anxious about his upcoming dental surgery". I like anxious because it feels like it means your heart is going to race, but the reason it is racing is up to you.

Comment: I use anxious more in the meaning of "nervously awaiting" and not so much as a negative feeling by itself.

Answer (score 6):

Alarmed, I leaned over to have a look for myself.

Comment: Alarmed conjures images of alertness and action to my mind, which I think goes beyond the level of "advanced curiosity" the OP was aiming for.

Comment: His wife's hands were shaking, no?

Comment: Yep, totally missed that on the first read, which makes it a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

If curious is your best adjective and you have already stated quite clearly the type of curiosity, I would suggest "apprehensively curious" for your solution.

There is no word that exemplifies curiosity with an undertone of worry.  Perhaps this is because the two are somewhat in opposition.  Saying "curious, yet apprehensive" might actually be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Would **worried about** fit?

> **worry about** [sth/sb] *vtr phrasal insep*
>
> > be concerned or anxious about

Answer (score 1):

I would say you looked over her shoulder with **trepidation**.

> a feeling of fear or agitation about something that may happen.

Comment: No. trepidation doesn't imply curious. Only fear.

Comment: Hmm.. 'curious' = "eager to know or learn something." 'Trepidation' may not have the 'eagerness' of full curiosity, but I think if you're feeling fear at the same time then eagerness is going to be tempered anyway.  I think 'trepidation' does still retain enough of a sense of anticipation about what's going to happen, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were **morbidly curious**.

morbid (ˈmɔːbɪd) adjective -[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Morbid)

> 1. (Psychology) having an unusual interest in death or unpleasant events

Comment: Truly concerned for your wife, you'd of asked *what's the problem*. Peaking at the paper was to satisfy your morbid curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Apprehensive (adj.)

> 1. anxious or fearful that something bad or unpleasant will happen.
> 2. *archaic literary* of or relating to perception or understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If the "curiosity" aspect is more important, you might use **intrigued**.

This also has a faint hint of risk or danger by association with the idea of *an intrigue*, a secret or illicit plan. One can be *intrigued* by something that one is also afraid of, where it wouldn't be appropriate to use *interested*, for example.

Comment: Is there any evidence that *intrigued,* used in its first sense of interested/fascinated actually carries any connotation of danger, however faint? If you are merely speculating that it might do this for some people, better to say so.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be best to describe the effect: "Anxiously holding my breath, a question in my eyes, I leaned over..."

Some such description will not be the shortest answer, but it may evoke the clearest picture.